# Generated model classes does not contain referenced objects

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, scaffolding

I am trying to use scaffolding to make a database-first application but have run into a problem.

Using the database as specified here:

```
CREATE TABLE Group (
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE Person ( 
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    GroupId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Group(Id) NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

I generate classes for accessing the database using `scaffold`.
But the generated `Group` class does give access to the persons in the group.
If I try to access the persons in a group like this:

```
var personsInGroup = myGroup.Persons.ToList();
```

The `personsInGroup`-list is empty, even though if I check the database, all the `Person`s have a `GroupId`.

Instead I have to find the persons in the group like this:

```
var personsInGroup = context.Persons.Where(p => p.GroupId == myGroup.Id).ToList();
```

Am I doing something wrong or have I misunderstood how these generated classes work?

Comment: Read Loading Related Data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@David Browne pointed me to read up on [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/), where I, indeed, found the answer to my question.

The trick was to specify that I want the Person data when I get the Group data from the database. It can be done like this:

```
var group = context.Groups
    .Include(g => g.Persons)
    .First();

var personsInGroup = group.Persons;
```